# Problem in matching string with awk regex

Tags: regex, awk

I´m trying to match the following sentence

ldcValue  = 0.00

The regex i´m trying to create must match:

- Left of the relational operator must be a variable that initiate with "ldc" as a prefix.
- In the middle must be a relation operator "<" ,">", "=", ">=" , "<="
- In the right must be a variable that initiate with "ldc" as a prefix or a number like "0.0" or "0.0d"

I have tried this regex:

```
if(match(line, "/(\<(ldc)\w*)(\t| )+(\=|>|<|>=|<=)\(\t| )*(\<(ldc)\w*)|\w*") > 0){ 
        print "match: "substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
    }
```

but didn't match.

Input examples

```
ldcValue > 0.00
ldcValue = 0
ldblValue = ad_value / llDias
ldcValue = ad_Value * ldblFator
```

Expected output matched:

```
   ldcValue > 0.00
   ldcValue = 0
```

What is the correct regex?

Thanks.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide sample input with a few lines that do and don't match your target string and the expected output from that. Make sure the input covers the non-trivial cases like strings that start with `fooldcValue` and strings that have `ldcValue !- 0.0`, etc. and so could be difficult for a script to NOT match incorrectly. Also include cases where there are multiplt matches on a single line if such exist.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions , but no need to add non trivial examples, as i know for sure that won´t happen in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Awk, put either quotes or slashes around your regex, but not both. Your current attempt requires a literal slash before the first `ldc`.

Also, traditional Awk does not typically support `\w` which is a Perl extension.

Try

```
/\<ldc[A-Za-z0-9_]+[ \t]*([><]=|[<>=])[ \t]*(ldc[A-Za-z0-9_]|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?d?)/
```

Your problem statement vaguely sounds like you need a proper parser, not just a regex, though.

Comment: and prefer static patterns than dynamic ones.

Comment: GNU awk does support `\w` and I wonder if `\<` is POSIX or supported only by specific implementations

Comment: You´re correct, we are using \w in our entire script and does works well!

Comment: @Sundeep `\<` is gawk specific.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works perfectly well, and i abreviated your regex using \w and works well: /\<ldc\w*+[ \t]*([><]=|[<>=])[ \t]*(ldc\w*|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?d?)/)

Comment: You could also replace `[ \t]` with `\s`. Btw `([><]=|[<>=])` would match `<<` - not sure if that's acceptable, it should really be `([<>]=?|=)`.

Comment: @EdMorton Huh? That matches `<` or `>` followed by `=`, or any of those three alone, just like your proposed alternative.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I misread it and thought the `=` was inside the first bracket expression same as the second one - I thought you were trying to create a (non-existent) difference between the two bracket expressions based on `><` in the first one vs `<>` in the 2nd one.